# Can't connect bluetooth headphones anymore

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I believe after an update I lost connection to my bluetooth headset, which was working fine but now it fails to connect with an error message of `Connection Failed:  Protocol not available` I'm on OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 and Kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic

```
╰─$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth                                                                        130 ↵
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-07-30 09:27:39 +03; 13min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 2403102 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38324)
     Memory: 1.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─2403102 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=avrcp

Tem 30 09:27:39 bluetoothd[2403102]: Starting SDP server
Tem 30 09:27:39 bluetoothd[2403102]: Excluding (cli) avrcp
Tem 30 09:27:39 bluetoothd[2403102]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
Tem 30 09:27:39 bluetoothd[2403102]: Failed to set mode: Not Supported (0x0c)
Tem 30 09:39:10 bluetoothd[2403102]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:01:D7:23: Protocol not >
Tem 30 09:39:10 bluetoothd[2403102]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:01:D7:23: Protocol no>
Tem 30 09:39:21 bluetoothd[2403102]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:01:D7:23: Protocol not >
Tem 30 09:39:21 bluetoothd[2403102]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:01:D7:23: Protocol no>
Tem 30 09:39:26 bluetoothd[2403102]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:01:D7:23: Protocol not >
Tem 30 09:39:26 bluetoothd[2403102]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for F4:4E:04:01:D7:23: Protocol no>
lines 1-21/21 (END)


╰─$ pactl info
    Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
    Library Protocol Version: 33
    Server Protocol Version: 35
    Is Local: yes
    Client Index: 51520
    Tile Size: 65472
    Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.56)
    Server Version: 15.0.0
    Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.4.iec958-stereo
    Default Source: alsa_input.usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_A35E7F4F-02.analog-stereo
    Cookie: c74a:d65d
```

Answer (score 1):

Run these two commands:

`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

`killall pulseaudio`

Try to connect again.

[Solution source](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/547)

Comment: Please be a little cautious with using *exact* copy and paste answers for slightly different questions on AU...

Comment: @andrew.46 Yes, but this answer worked for me with the exact same question as ggnoredo's.